# Newton's law of Cooling, no initial temperature

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm stuck on this apparently difficult problem.

An object is placed in a a room with a temp of 20 C. the temp of the object drops by 5 C in 4 min and by 7 C in 8 min. What was the initial temp of the object when it was placed in the room?

$T(t) = Ce^{kt} + 20$

(4, Ce + 15) (8, Ce + 13)

$Ce + 15 = Ce^{4k} +20$

$Ce + 13 = Ce^{8k} +20$

$e^{8k} + 2 = e^{4k}$

$k = \frac{ln2}{-4}$

I probably misunderstood the problem.

I'd greatly appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The law may indeed be written $T(t)=20 + C \exp(-kt)$ (I choose $k>0$, $t$ in minutes).
Letting $\gamma= \exp(- 4k )$, $\gamma^2=\exp(-8k)$ 
 we have $T(0)-T(4) = C (1-\gamma) = 5$ and $T(0)-T(8)=C(1-\gamma^2)=7$ (if I have understood correctly your statement about temperature drops, if not you should adjust).
From this
$$ \frac{7}{5} = \frac{T(0)-T(8)}{T(0)-T(4) }=\frac{1-\gamma^2}{1-\gamma}=1+\gamma$$
yielding $\gamma=2/5$. Substituting back $C=25/3$ and $T(0)=20+25/3=28.33$

Answer (score 1):

Newton's Law of Cooling: $\frac{dT}{dt}=k(T_e-T)$

Has the solution $T(t)=T_e+(T_0-T_e)e^{-kt}$
where $T_0=T(0)$ is the object's initial temperature we are going to find
and $T_e$ is the environment temperature

In this case $T_e=20^{\circ}C$; then we can write

$T(t)=20+(T_0-20)e^{-kt}$

Now, we know that

$T(4)=T_0-5=20+(T_0-20)e^{-k(4)}$
$T(8)=T_0-7=20+(T_0-20)e^{-k(8)}$

$T_0-25=(T_0-20)e^{-k(4)}$
$T_0-27=(T_0-20)e^{-k(8)}$

$e^{-4k}=\frac{T_0-25}{T_0-20}$;$\hspace{10 mm}$ 
$e^{-8k}=\frac{T_0-27}{T_0-20}$

$-4k=ln\frac{T_0-25}{T_0-20}$;$\hspace{10 mm}$ 
$-8k=ln\frac{T_0-27}{T_0-20}$

$2ln\frac{T_0-25}{T_0-20}=ln\frac{T_0-27}{T_0-20}$

$(\frac{T_0-25}{T_0-20})^2=\frac{T_0-27}{T_0-20}$

$(T_0-25)^2=(T_0-27)(T_0-20)$

Working on this equation we are left with $ 3T_0=85$ and $T_0=28.33^{\circ}C$

With this value we can find $k=0.25ln(2.50)$